# MYSQL help, how to count the results

Tags: mysql

Running this sql:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    base_item
FROM
    items
WHERE
    base_item = "202"
```

gives me this http://prntscr.com/9gwwxq
However, how do i expand the MYSQL query to add up the amount of 202 base_items a user_id has. e.g user_id 41 has 6.

Comment: No of item count against user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    count(base_item) as c
FROM
    items
WHERE
    base_item = "202"
group by
    user_id
```

Comment: No need to put `base_item` in the `count` function, just use `count(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the number of “202” base_items per user ID:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    items
WHERE
    base_item = "202"
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to `count` of similar base_item

```
SELECT
    user_id, 
    base_item, count(*) as user_no
FROM
    items
WHERE
    base_item = "202" 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: gives me this result http://prntscr.com/9gx0jp . I want the results to be like user_id 2 has 10 or the number they actually have.